# I'm making a website and I have a problem on my about us tab

Tags: html, css, web

[image: pic of problem]

Currently I only have a text paragraph only on my About Us page. I have a main Navigation and a Side Navigation bar. The Side Navigation bar is where the problem lies with the paragraph. I'm sure the paragraph is causing a spacing between the Title of the Nav bar (currently it says Collaborations Platforms/Consoles) My interest is having my Side Nav Bar under the title. The paragraph is supposed to be underneath and centered.

```css
.side-nav {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 130px;
  margin-left: -430px;
}

.side-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.side-nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: darkviolet;
}

.side-nav li.active a {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.side-nav li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

p2 {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: -410px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: darkviolet;
}
```

```html
<link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div class="header">
  <img src="images/icon.png" class="logo" alt="Logo" width="150" height="150" />
  <h1 style="color:darkviolet"> Collaborations </h1>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <a class="discord-button" onclick=" window.open('https://discord.gg/8yAfreq','_blank')"> Join Our Discord Server </a>
  <nav>
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="chat.html">Chat</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      </<ul>
  </nav>
  <p2><strong>Collaborations Platforms/Consoles<strong></p2>
        <nav>
          <ul class="side-nav">
            <li><a>Ps4</a></li>
            <li><a>XBox</a></li>
            <li><a>Switch</a></li>
            <li><a>PC</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <p style="color:white; font-size:175%;"> Collaborations is about bringing people together. People who make videos and live stream, whether it is on YouTube or on Twitch.
        Are you looking for a specific platform/console to collaborate on? We are sure we have it listed. So far we have collaborations on Ps4, XBox, Switch and,
        PC. If there is another platform/console that we have missed or forgot about please let us know and we will add it to the list. Now we understand that
        playing alone is fun sometimes, but playing with a friend is much better. Wouldn't you want to celebrate a sweet victory with a friend, group, or team?
        We sure believe it is much more fun! Come and join us see who wants to collaborate with YOU!           </p>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the paragraph is currently under the side nav? Because if it is, it's a float problem.

Comment: No the paragraph is in between the nav title(something I might change later) and the actual nav bar

Comment: if I could add a picture of what it looks like it would be a better visual

Comment: I was just about to ask that. Could you add it? You should be able to from the editor.

Comment: I will try to see if I can

Comment: the picture was added as a click link and takes you to imgur

Comment: I think I know the problem. Try reducing `margin-top:` on `.side-nav` and see if that helps.

Comment: ok I will try that

Comment: Ok that worked.... Idk why that worked I thought I had tried that apparently I didn't... Thank you

Comment: wait that works on that page but it changes on the other pages

Comment: What's wrong with the other pages? Could you post a pic and some code?

Comment: There is a lot going wrong with your code @BeardedProductions. I would recommend in investing in an [HTML Linter](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options) so you can fix your markup before you try and troubleshoot anything. Secondly, not all browsers support custom tags completely yet, so unless you are on one of those browers, and expect other people to be as well, its best to stay away from custom tags (`<p2>`). You should fix your invalid markup and include your CSS so we can help after those are narrowed down